# Report Item not linked to a Dataset - tablix in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2015, dataset, reporting

I am trying to create a Report in SSRS and I have the below Table grouped by Closer - 
[image]

I am trying to add a Pagename so each tab is separated by the Closer name when exported to Excel. When I go to Pagename in Table properties and click on "Expression" ,  I get Report Item not Linked to a Dataset for fields. How do I get to see the fields so I can pick it.

- [image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!
JHegde

Answer (score 0):

The value for Pagename is set via the Tablix properties of Closer. Expand the "Group", the subgroup "PageBreak" appears, now set the value for the Pagename here.

Pagename can only be used in headers or footers.

Make sure within your Row Group properties of closer you have ticked "set between each instance of a group"  - this creates the page tabs when exported to excel.

Answer (score 0):

Click on a row or column header in the tablix and then click the tablix selector handle (4 pointed arrow) in the top left corner. This is just to ensure you have the tablix selected correctly.

Hit F4 and you should the datset property in the properties pane.

[image]

Select the correct dataset from the drop down list.

To be honest I'm surprised you are getting this error, as you have fields in the tablix and row groups already setup up. To do this, would mean you almost certainly had the dataset correct at the time. It could be that the setting was accidentally deleted I guess.. Anyway, try this and let us know how you get on.